# Linking against so library without header files via objdump

Tags: c++, header, shared-libraries, objdump

So I have an .so file with no header files that I want to compile code and link against(long story)

Anyway, I got objdump to output demangled headers

```
objdump -g -x -C libglo_crc.so
```

And I get results like this:

```
long int Calculate_Message_CRC__FUcPUc (int iLength /* 0x8 */, unsigned char *iMess /* 0xc */)
```

So I know that this is the mangled name, and I create a prototype like this:

```
long int Calculate_Message_CRC(unsigned char, unsigned char *);
```

and then try to invoke the Calculate_Message_CRC function, but I always end up with an undefined reference error:

```
g++ test.cpp -L. -l glo_crc
undefined reference to `Calculate_Message_CRC(unsigned char, unsigned char*)'
```

Am I doing something wrong?  How else can I link against this library without headers provided by the vendor?

Comment: Are you certain that you copied the signatures of the demangled name and the prototype correctly? If yes, then your prototype does not match the function, because its first argument is `int` and not `unsigned char`

Comment: Looks like the first argument is an int and not a char.

Comment: I tried both int and unsigned char, neither worked.

Comment: Isn't -C supposed to demangle?  Are you sure the library was compiled with the same compiler?

Answer (score 0):

- As already been said, check the first argument it must be `int`, not `usigned char`.
- I see `objdump -g -x -C libglo_bc.so` in your question, but you're linking against `glo_crc` (`-l glo_crc`). Why? Compiler will search for library with the name like `libglo_crc.so`, but according to your question, function `Calculate_Message_CRC` is in `libglo_bc.so`. Is it typo? Or I missed something?

UPD1:
As **Steve C** said: are you sure the library has been compiled with the same compiler? Mangling strongly depends on the compiler. One compiler can mange `Calculate_Message_CRC` to `Calculate_Message_CRC_FUcPUc` while other can mangle it like `Calculate_Message_CRC_XUzFUz`. You can use `nm` and `grep` to find `Calculate_Message_CRC` in your code to see mangled name. Is it the same as in `libglo_crc.so`?